# Save a pdf file in Capacitor

Tags: angular, capacitor

I'm using angular + capacitor.

I'm able to save/write a txt file using appendFile or writeFile
But i'm unable to save a file from external path

Note: I'm using jsPDF to save my html file to pdf.